# Interfacing 64Kx16 bit SRAM with Qsys

Tags: fpga, sram, quartus

I have two 64Kx8 bit memory chips which I have connected to an FPGA configured using Qsys as a single 64Kx16 block. I have used a [Generic Tri-state controller](http://www.altera.com/literature/ug/ug_avalon_tc.pdf) as interface, with both address width and data width set to 16:

[image]

Unfortunately, this doesn't produce the result I want (which is to have a single 128KB block of RAM with 16-bit access). My controller occupies only 64KB of address space. It looks like Qsys treats my SRAM as 32Kx16 block with 16-bit address bus which allows addressing individual bytes.

Is there a way to configure my controller in a way that makes the whole 128KB of memory accessible? Here's a diagram of connections between the chips:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGhFwY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: To be sure - chips are SRAM (24512-15), not DRAM and not SDRAM? Then why not just design very simple memory controller which would set address, wait required number of cycles and get data read (or have data written)?

Comment: @Anonymous, but that's not providing an answer, that's trying to redefine the question :-)

Comment: @TonyM absolutely correct, sometimes it is better to change course of actions/strategy/architecture so that tough questions simply do not appear. Why hitting against wall if it is just as simple as doing things slightly differently? :)

Comment: @Anonymous Yep, plain and simple SRAM. That "Generic tri-state controller" is supposed to do just what you describe. I know I could design one myself, but that would take more than 5 minutes that using this wizard would take.

Comment: Dmitry, you already spent more that 5 mins on it :) generally applicability of this module is defined by the way you physically connect chips to FPGA. Please attach circuit diagram.

Comment: Sorry @Anonymous, I was busy commenting below. True but consider the weight of what you're suggesting, as outlined below. Let's not abandon ship in at the first sight of trouble :-)

Comment: @Anonymous That's a learning curve I'm willing to accept so that I don't have to write trivial verilog code again and again when I need to attach a memory block to my system.

Comment: What kind of access do you want? It is not possible to do byte level access because there are no byte enables (if you had connected both CS2 pins to the FPGA separately, then those could form your byte enable). But you should have access to the whole 64k map through the 16bit interface - you just have to make sure all your accesses are always 16 bit to avoid data loss.

Comment: Oh, duh. You should set the address width to 17 bits and not use the LSB. The addresses on the Tri-State controller are always byte address, not word addresses. As long as you are always writing both bytes at the same time, and always write to even addresses, it is safe to drop the LSB.

Comment: (p.s. the duh was aimed at myself, I suddenly remembered the addressing modes as I was typing a different comment).

Comment: @TomCarpenter This idea crossed my mind at some point, but it looked like a dirty workaround. Say, if I use the bridge as you suggested, will it handle single byte accesses for me? Or will it just drop the LSb? (I don't need byte access in this project, but I might need it in future projects)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev the way you have connected your RAM, single byte access is not possible (you would have to do manual Read-Modify-Write). The Avalon-MM fabric that is added between the pipeline bridge and the memory will convert the LSB into a byte-enable signal, so if in the future you added byte-enable signals to you memory ICs, you won't need to recompile anything.

Comment: @TomCarpenter So, Read-Modify-Write is not something an avalon bridge could pull out on its own? Not that I'm surprised it doesn't, it's just funny that a whole IP core will be there to essentially drop an LSb for me.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Sadly you have to do R-M-W yourself. Qsys systems end up with quite a lot of random IP cores which do pretty much nothing but rearrange signals. It's the price you pay for graphical interfaces. The huge system I've developed over the years has pretty much 1000 IP core instances, of which probably 50-75% are purely custom pass-through cores there solely to get Qsys to connect things up properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is one of how Qsys treats addresses. There are two ways in which an Avalon-MM interface can represent its address - as a "symbol address", and as a "word address".

For slaves which are defined with an address unit of **SYMBOLS**, the LSB represents one symbol (aka the width of one unit in the data bus, e.g. a byte). For an address defined in units of **WORDS**, the LSB represents one word (aka the width of the data bus). In the case of the Generic Tristate Controller, its Avalon-MM interface is defined in terms of symbols as indicated in the screenshot below:

[image: Address Units]

What this means is that the LSB represents a single 8bit symbol. You have 128k symbols of memory which means you need to specify a 17bit address *not* a 16bit address. The extra bit is due to the fact that you have two symbols per word.

To interface with your memory, you then simply ignore the LSB. The only thing to make sure of when doing this is that you always access the correct address (with LSB tied to zero), and always perform 16bit data accesses by making sure the both byte enable bits are high.

If you want to convert the address units to **WORDS**, the simplest way is to insert an Avalon-MM Pipeline Bridge. Set the following parameters:

- Data Width to 16
- Symbol Width to 8
- Address Units to WORDS
- Check the box saying "Use automatically-determined address width"
- Uncheck both "Pipeline Command Signals" and "Pipeline Response Signals".

You should find that it calculates a word address width of 16 bits. All accesses on the slave of the pipeline bridge will now be in terms of word addresses meaning it will have a 16bit address bus. By unchecking the "Pipeline" boxes, the resulting IP core will have no logic in it at all - it will simply pass through all signals directly.

Qsys will automatically insert Avalon-MM fabric components to map the Word addressed master of the pipeline bridge to the Symbol addressed slave of the Generic Tristate Controller, taking care of translating the 16bit word address to a 17bit symbol address for you.

---

In case you are wondering, I know this works because I came across the same issue with a CFI device on one of the dev kits I am using whereby it was two separate ICs connected together in parallel - though in that case it was two 16bit ICs forming a 32bit bus, and I needed byte level access so the connections got slightly more tricky.

Comment: Excellent and definitive answer, upvoted. Why on earth couldn't they use the universally-accepted word 'byte' instead of 'symbol'?

Comment: @TonyM because a symbol is not necessarily a byte, it can be any width. A word is the width of the data bus, so it is also possible for word and symbol to both be the same width.

Comment: Ah, I got the wrong end of the stick :-) Thanks, Tom.

Comment: Hi Tom, I got it working by assigning a 17-bit address to the tri-state controller and ignoring the LSb. Interestingly, inserting a bridge between the controller and the CPU to convert words to symbols didn't have any effect: no matter how I configured the *Address Units* and *Address width*, I still have to give my controller a 17-bit address for the RAM test to pass. So I ended up removing the bridge altogether.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev assuming you are using Nios, all addresses are always byte addresses in Nios, regardless of the interface (it does the conversion internally).

Comment: Yes, I do, and yes, I understand that. I was expecting the bridge to translate a 17-bit address on the Nios side into a 16-bit address on the tri-state controller side. That didn't happen; I still had to configure the controller to have 17-bit address to make it work properly, so the bridge didn't do anything at all. As a side note, I seem to use a different version of Quartus (13.0, the last one with Cyclone II support), perhaps that's the reason I don't get the same results you did.

Answer (score 1):

I did not use this IP, but what I see from the picture:

- address width: 16 bits, this means there will be 65536 words of *data width*;
- data width: 16 bits, this means 2 bytes;
- bytes per words: 2, which is 16/2=8 seems to be correct value;
- byte enable width: 2, meaning 2 wires which disable/enable action on hi-low bytes of the data width of 16 bits (however byte enable is disabled = controller will read/write whole 16-bit data bus, no partial access).

Controller sees 65536 words by 16 bytes, thus 128 kilobytes, and assumes that it can access 16 bits at once *not* being able to mask respective byte in the word.

How did you connect SRAM chips? Just connected two chips in parallel with address lines and CE/OE?

So:

> My controller occupies only 64KB of address space

Correct.

> and unaligned access to this RAM fails

Controller sees 16 bit data, and can read/write only in 16-bit words. To get byte out of it you need to check lowest bit of *17-bit address* (with highest 16-bit address being on A0-A15 lines), and activate respective chip (using its CE) for operation, then multiplex data from/to respective data group (A0-A7 or A8-A15). But if you connected CEs together you will not be able to access chips separately.

CEs should act as 17th bit of the address. What I explained above is just one of the options how it can be implemented. You need to revise your circuit, and as I said in the comment to your question, it would be much simpler and effective to design your own controller (and this controller may be more predictable).

**Update after circuit diagram addition:**

In this configuration whole 128 kilobytes are addressable, but only in 16-bit words. You will not be able to address RAM in individual 8-bit words (bytes).

However what you can do with it: you may consider enabling byte enable, and attaching chip select to byte enable signals. However, anyway, you will have to multiplex data from D7-D0 or D15-D8 into 8-bit register in FPGA.

Comment: It's only simpler if the OP has the experience and confidence to define a controller and it's only effective if they have the time and funds to design, develop, testbench, prove and document it. Doing the latter properly is a couple of days work at least, maybe a week. How is that simpler and more effective than pulling up IP they should take an hour? This OP's having trouble but loads of people will have used it that quickly. Can you explain that one to me? :-)

Comment: @TonyM sure you are right, that's why these building blocks are in there. Connection circuit will define the exact answer. How address is connected, CE, OE?

Comment: Correct and the rest of the stuff you're answer covers is good stuff.

Comment: I could add a 17-th bit of address, but that sound like a dirty workaround since I don't want to access individual bytes (and in my configuration it's impossible anyway)

Comment: See update to the answer. Then what you mean when saying in question "unaligned access to this RAM fails"? You want access to be aligned to what? You have 65536 words of 16-bit width.

Comment: May setting "byteenable width" to 1 help?

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, adding byteenable signals means I'll have modify my PCB. Forget about unaligned access, it actually works fine. I just see half of the RAM I want.

Comment: @Anonymous Setting byteenable width to 1 results in `Error: sram_controller_0.tdt.avalon_universal_slave_0: byteenable[1] width must be 2 (data width/8)`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for trying. So let's summarize: your RAM hardware is purely 65536 x 16 (external configuration), but you can access only half of it. It could be either 32768 x 16 as you said in question, or 65536 x 8. May it happen that you attach this controller incorrectly to other internals within FPGA? (e.g. internally data bus is organized as 8 bits, or it thinks data bus is 15 bits and not 16 bits)?

Comment: I highly doubt that I could connect something incorrectly: the wizard generates a component which has those `A` `OE` `WE` and `DQ` signals which I export directly to pins. I'm pretty certain that I have missed a checkbox or used the wrong controller here.

Comment: No, not those signals which look into the SRAM direction. I mean other side of this *Avalon Tri-State Conduit* circuit, which looks "inside" the FPGA.